# Visual Studio 2019 environment cannot find some files in Windows\System32

Tags: windows, visual-studio

In my Visual Studio solution, I added a post-build step to get some files from Windows\System32, but for some reason it could copy one file, but not another.

The two files were vcruntime140.dll and vcruntime_1.dll respectively.

Digging deeper, I found that Visual Studio could only *see* one file and not the other. In fact, there are a *lot* of files it somehow cannot find.

I fired up the Developer Command Prompt in Visual Studio and looked for all the dll files in Windows\System32, simply with `dir *.dll`, and found **2485 files**. I then fired up `cmd.exe` as a separate window and ran the same command, but this time found **3738 files**.

This was the same result whether I ran Visual Studio as an Admin or not.

Security-wise, the files which could be seen had the same permissions as the files that were unseen.

Has anyone seen this before, and have a fix?